# Random key values from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list

New to using Python

I have a list, full of dictionaries with country names and their capitals, from the list I want to randomly grab the key value from country, display a question, "What is the capital of Australia?  I then want to randomly select two other capitals from my list, as well as the correct answer, shuffle them and get the user to select their choice. I have a VERY rough Idea.  I'm fine with print and asking for input and all that.  The main issue is, how do I make the list of answers to include the correct answer, plus the two random answers.  I hope from what is below you can see what I'm trying to do.

```
Alist = [{country": "Australia", "capital": "Canberra"} {country": "UK", "capital": "London"}.....] #list goes on

AnswerList[ ]

randomCountry = random.choice(Alist, ['country'])

randomAnswers = random.sample(Alist, ['capital'], 2)

AnswerList.append (randomAnswers) #not sure on how to get the correct answer in here

random.shuffle(AnswerList)
```

Comment: Simplest thing is to keep a dictionary that maps countries  to capitals instead of a list of dicts that, etc. Then you can just pick both the answer and the diversions from a list of countries. If you want to check an answer, simply check the dictionary.  Take a look at PEP8 for naming conventions so your code is more readable when you have other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on pvgs comment, using a slightly different data structure may be a little bit clearer in this case

```
import random

pool={"Australia":"Canberra",
      "United Kingdom":"London",
      "Germany":"Berlin",
      "France":"Paris",
      "Brasil":"Brasília",
      "Thailand":"Bangkok"}
totalAnswersOffered=3
```

This way you can directly access the capital of a country: `pool["France"]` yields `Paris`.

Select a random country from the list of available country names and add correct answer to a list:

```
randomCountry = random.choice(list(pool.keys()))
answerList = [pool[randomCountry]]
```

Then fill the list with different, wrong answers:

```
while len(answerList)<totalAnswersOffered:
    randomAnswer = random.choice(list(pool.values()))
    if randomAnswer not in answerList:
        answerList.append(randomAnswer)
```

And finally randomize the order:

```
random.shuffle(answerList)
```

An example of the result would be this:

```
>>> print(randomCountry, answerList)
Thailand ['London', 'Bangkok', 'Paris']
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think that only works if you cast `pool.items()` to a list explicitly before using `random.choice()` on it. Since I would then have to add the correct_capital to the list of answers, I think I'll stick with my approach.

Answer (score -1):

```
right = Alist[<rightKey>]

AnswerList.append(right)

wrong = list(Alist.keys())
wrong.remove(<rightKey>)

for key in random.sample(wrong, 2):
    AnswerList.append(Alist[key])

random.shuffle(AnswerList)
```